# I'm a beginner using CodeIgniter, I get an error message like this A Database Error Occurred, thank

Tags: codeigniter-3

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `user` (`name`, `email`, `image`, `password`, `role_id`, `is_active`, `date_created`)

Filename: P:/Website/wpu/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

"return $this->display_error(array('Error Number: '.$error['code'], $error['message'], $sql));"

Comment: please check your Database fields And your Inserted field Mostly first check password Spelling capitalize or smaller

Comment: The error is pretty clear - it says you're trying to use a field (`password`) which doesn't exist.